# The disk algebra and continuous homomorphisms

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

The disk algebra is the set of continuous functions $f: D \to \mathbb C$ where $D$ is the closed unit disc in $\mathbb C$ and $f$ is analytic on the interior of $D$. It is endowed with the $\sup$-norm.

Let $A$ denote the disk algebra.

I read that every continuous homomorphism $\varphi : A \to \mathbb C$ is of the form $f \mapsto f(z_0)$ for some $z_0 \in D$. The problem is I tried to look up the proof but I can't remember where I read it and I also can't find an alternative source. I also can't seem to prove it. I'm even starting to doubt the truth of the statement. How to prove this?

Comment: For the fact that the space of polynomials is dense in $A$, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644741/disk-algebra-norm-clousre).

Comment: @DanielFischer I now also think the statement as I give it in the question is wrong: it should be every **unital** continuous homomorphism. Shouldn't it?

Comment: That depends on which definition of a (ring/algebra) homomorphism you use. If the one without requiring $\varphi(1) = 1$, then you need to say "unital". If the other one, saying "unital homomorphism" would be pleonastic (specifying continuity is, if I remember correctly, not necessary, I think an algebra homomorphism $A\to\mathbb{C}$ is automatically continuous). The answer is good except for using the wrong argument for the denseness of polynomials.

Comment: For others encountering the issues OP ran into with finding resources, a key idea to look up is "multiplicative linear functional". This will help with hunting for resources.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varphi : A\to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous homomorphism, and let $f \in A$ be the function $z\mapsto z$, and let $z_0 := \varphi(f)$. Then for any polynomial
$$
g(z) := \sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_k z^k \Rightarrow g = \sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_k f^k
$$
we have
$$
\varphi(g) = \sum_{k=0}^n \alpha_k z_0^k = g(z_0)
$$
Now the set of such polynomials is dense in $A$ (by Stone-Weierstrass), and hence $\varphi(g) = g(z_0)$ for all $g\in A$.

Comment: Thanks. And how to finish the proof? 
$$ 0 = \|\varphi(f-f)\| = \|\varphi(f-\lim_{n \to \infty}p_n)\| =  \|\varphi(f)-\lim_{n \to \infty}\varphi(p_n))\| = \|\varphi(f)-\lim_{n \to \infty}\lambda \| =  \|\varphi(f)-\lambda \|$$?

Comment: What is $\lambda$? You just need to reprove the fact that if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are two continuous linear functionals that agree on a dense set, then they agree everywhere.

Comment: $\lambda$ is the constant function $f(x) = \lambda$ for all $x$.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain why $\varphi(\overline{z}) = \overline{z_0}$? If this does not hold you can't apply Stone Weierstrass.

Comment: There is a nicer argument for the reasoning. You can prove that the closed subalgebra generated by $1$ and $f$ is equal to $A$, and then the statement follows.